# How to show a grid of Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a form with two fields:

- the first one allows to enter a city
- the second one allows to enter an address

Given these two data should I use the Google API to create a map. 
Each time the button is clicked the form creates a new map. 
I did it this way.

**HTML Code**:

```
<form method="post" action="../public/maps.php" id="upload">
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td>City:</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city"/></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td>Address:</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"/></td>                           
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <input type="submit" name="submit-maps" value="Post" onClick="createMap()"/>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<div id="content_map-canvas"></div>
```

**Javascript code**:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var city;
var address;
var count = 0;

function createMap() {
    var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;   
    var city_address = city+address;
    var description = city+address;
    showMap(city_address, description);
}

function showMap(city_address, description) {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var options = {
         zoom: 8, 
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
      };

   //Creates the new div  
   count = count + 1;
   var id = "map-canvas" + count;
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.id = id;
   document.getElementById('content_map-canvas').appendChild(div);

   //Creates the map
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), options);
   geocoding(city_address, description);
}

function geocoding(city_address, description) {
  geocoder.geocode({'address': city_address}, function(results, status) {
    if(status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker
            ({map: map, 
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              title: description 
      });
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);

      contentString = description;
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
      }); 

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
  });      
}
```

That code does not work. When I click the button, do not make a map..
I've never worked with the Google API so I'll definitely made a stupid mistake. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issues:

- Your map divs (that you create dynamically) do not have a size (so you can't see them).

  ```
  div.style.width= "300px";
  div.style.height= "300px";
  ```
- Your form processing function needs to return false, or the page will reload.

  ```
  <input type="submit" name="submit-maps" value="Post" onClick="createMap(); return false;"/>
  ```
- Your concatenation of the address fields makes the address invalid.

  ```
  var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;   
  var city_address = city+address;
  var description = city+address;
  showMap(city_address, description);
  ```

gives things like: city: New York, address: "100 Broadway" -> "New York100 Broadway", you probably want something that looks like an address to pass in:

```
    var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;   
    var city_address = address+", "+city;
    var description =  address+", "+city;
    showMap(city_address, description);
```

- If the geocoder "status" is not "OK", it silently fails, bad practice, add an else case:

  ```
  else alert("Geocode failed:"+status+", "+city_address);
  ```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleGeocodedMapsForm.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have corrected the code but it still does not work, does not create the div... Uhm...

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't create the div?  Is _your_ version of the code generating any javascript errors?

Comment: It means that when I write in the form a city and an address and I click the button, no div is created so maybe that's why you do not create the maps. The fact that the div does not create I see via inspect element in Chrome. the console does not generate errors

Comment: Compare your version to the [working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleGeocodedMapsForm.html)